# Programmatically setting the date selected in MS Chart?

Tags: .net, mschart, data-visualization

I'm using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

And, I want the user to be able go to a date by clicking on a gridview. I've tried setting CursorX or SelectionStart/End to the datetime (tooadate) in the gridview but it doesn't do anything.

Haven't found an example for this.. any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the scaleview property of each axis. This zooms into the desired area.